# Tic Tac Toe Game using Min-Max Algorithm

Tags: java, backtracking, tic-tac-toe, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

I added these 3 variable to make operation of finding the winner in O(1) time.

```
private final int[] rowSum, colSum;
private int diagSum;
private int revDiagSum;
```

rowSum array contains sum of each row in n * n board, similary colSum contains column sums and diagSum and revDiagSum contains sum in diagonal and reverse diagonal.

**Min-Max logic :**
// returns an array containing { x, y, score }
// n is board.size here.

```
private int[] minMax(int player, final int n) {
    // At max level --> human's turn | At min level --> Computer's turn 
    // MIN == -1 | MAX == +1

    int best[] = null;
    if(player == MIN) {
        best = new int[] {-1, -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE};
    }
    else if(player == MAX) {
        best = new int[] {-1, -1, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(board.get(i, j) == 0) {

                int win = tryMove(i, j, player);

                int []score = null;
                if((win != 0) || board.filled()) {
                    // if this is the last move we can play in game, score is calculated.
                    score = new int[] {i, j, win};
                }
                else {
                    score = minMax(-1 * player, n);
                }

                undoMove(i, j, player);

                if(player == MIN) {
                    if(score[2] < best[2]) {
                        best[0] = i;
                        best[1] = j;
                        best[2] = score[2];
                    }
                }
                else if(player == MAX) {
                    if(score[2] > best[2]) {
                        best[0] = i;
                        best[1] = j;
                        best[2] = score[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // return the optimal move(with score) player(=computer/human) can play by making a move.
    return best;
}

private int tryMove(int i, int j, int player) {
    int n = board.getSize();
    board.set(i, j, player);
    rowSum[i] += player;
    colSum[j] += player;
    if(i == j)
        diagSum += player;
    if(i + j == n - 1)
        revDiagSum += player;
    // if any of the sum == (+n / -n) means player won.
    if(rowSum[i] == Math.abs(n) || colSum[j] == Math.abs(n) || diagSum == Math.abs(n) || revDiagSum == Math.abs(n)) {
        return player;
    }
    return 0;
}

private int undoMove(int i, int j, int player) {
    int n = board.getSize();
    board.set(i, j, 0);
    rowSum[i] -= player ;
    colSum[j] -= player;
    if(i == j)
        diagSum -= player;
    if(i + j == n - 1)
        revDiagSum -= player;
    return 0;
}
```

I call the above Min-Max func() always like this :

```
int[] move = minMax(-1, n); // always consider computer as the min-player and human as max player.
```

> Now the issue I am facing is, whenever I am running this Game, I
> ("Human") am able to beat the computer which should not happen in the
> ideal case as PC plays optimal moves everytime against us.

Tried debugging, but couldn't figure what's the issue here.

**As per the logic, I am not able to suspect the issue in code.**

Complete Code: https://github.com/tusharRawat821/Tic-Tac-Toe

**Bug Fixed:**

```
Below piece of code should be updated:

if(rowSum[i] == Math.abs(n) || colSum[j] == Math.abs(n) || diagSum == Math.abs(n) || revDiagSum == Math.abs(n)) {
....}

Corrected if condition :

    if(Math.abs(rowSum[i]) == n || Math.abs(colSum[j]) == n || Math.abs(diagSum) == n || Math.abs(revDiagSum) == n) {
....}
```